# Como seleciono os últimos registros de entradas específicas?

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com registros de compras dos clientes, eu gostaria de selecionar somente a última compra de cada cliente. Como fazer isso? Tentei usar o DISTINCT, mas eu tenho outros dados de que preciso e não são possíveis agrupar, como a data.

Por exemplo:

Cliente A

```
Compra 1
Compra 2
```

Cliente B

```
Compra 1
Compra 2
```

Cliente C

```
Compra 1
Compra 2
Compra 3
```

O Resultado deve ser:

```
Cliente A Compra 2
Cliente B Compra 2
Cliente C Compra 3
```

Comment: você pode fazer uma sub-consulta para trazer essa informação, ou left join tb

Comment: Fernando, você poderia passar mais informações sobre a tabela?  falar qual é o tipo do dado armazenado na coluna de com `Compra 1`, essa tabela possui alguma coluna de id? essa informações são importates para um solução mais adequada a seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode particionar a consultar utilizando a `window function` `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
WITH CTE_Compras AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClienteId ORDER BY CompraId DESC) AS Ordem
        ClienteId,
        CompraId
    FROM Compras
)

SELECT ClienteId, CompraId FROM CTE_Compras WHERE Ordem = 1
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem essa função, mas eu consegui aplicar e resolver meu problema. Vou ler mais sobre e tentar entender melhor, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

já tentou utilizar `MAX` no campo Compra, agrupando o cliente ? veja o exemplo abaixo se te atende. Obs: estou considerando o campo COMPRA como um `int`por isso está funcionando.

```
declare @Compras as Table (Cliente varchar(1), Compra int)
declare @Cliente int

insert into @Compras (Cliente, Compra)
Values ('A',1),('A',2),('A',3),('B',1),('B',2),('C',1),('C',2),('C',3),('C',4)

-- ====================================
-- Exibindo todas as compras 
-- ====================================

SELECT Cliente, Compra
  FROM @Compras

-- ====================================
-- Exibindo o ultimo registro de compra 
-- ====================================

SELECT Cliente , MAX(Compra) as Compra
  FROM @Compras
 GRoup by Cliente
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando:
    create table Compra (IDCompra int, Cliente varchar(1))

```
insert into Compra (IDCompra, CLiente)
select 1, 'A'
union select 2, 'A'
union select 1 ,'B'
union select 2 ,'B'
union select 3 ,'B'
union select 1 ,'C'
union select 2 ,'C'
union select 3 ,'C'
union select 4 ,'C'


select
    *
from
    Compra c
where
    Exists
    (
    select max(IDCompra) from Compra cAux
    where c.Cliente = cAux.Cliente
    group by Cliente
    having max(IDCompra) = c.IDCompra
)
```